#  Advantage Database Server 10 - Error 1500

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-2009, advantage-database-server

I got an application (written in Delphi 2009) that uses an ADS Server (Version 10.10).
I'm using the TDataSet Components to access the database.

On my dev machine everything is ok.
But on a test machine (also with ADS 10.10), I get the error 1500 when trying to open an TAdsQuery that selects data from a table containing unicode fields.

The knowledge database says that the files aicu.dll and icudt40l.dat must be presend on both client and server. I've checked this on both machines, and they are present in the Advantage 10.10\Server directory.

Maybe somebody else experienced this error and can give me a hint what's wrong there?
Thanks!

Comment: There is no `1500` error for ADS. Can you provide the *exact* error message you're receiving? (Note I asked for the **message** as well as the error code.)

Comment: From the help file: 1500 Failed to load Unicode support DLL or Shared Object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should put the `aicu32.dll` and `icudt40l.dat` either into your application directory or into the System32/SysWOW64 folder on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

For Unicode support in Advantage Database Server read:
http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=42&ID=77

There stays:

> Additional files are required to support Unicode, aciu.dll and icudt40l.dat. The aicu.dll contains the Unicode functions used by
>   Advantage and Unicode collations are stored in the .dat file. These
>   files take up approximately 15MB of disk space and must be distributed
>   with both the client and server when using Unicode field types.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13052834)

Comment: It is possible I am blind and also it possible I have hallucinations .. I put the citation from the website in _italic_ under that link .. now is the citation yellow (thanks to Ari0nhh I think, truly I love it but I don't know how to do it). 
I can also see that I've become -1 .. nice. I shouldn't really drink that much coffee.